# Websphere 6.1 ejb3 authenticating user and mapping to role

Tags: security, authentication, ejb-3.0, websphere, roles

I'm upgrading an application from an old ejb2 setup to use ejb3's using the ejb3 feature pack on websphere 6.1

I've got a ServletContextListener which does some initialisation when the servlet context starts, part of this initialisation involves calling ejb's.

The server is set up to use FileRegistrySample for its custom user registry, and on the old ejb2 setup it succesfully authenticates the system as the admin console user, and maps it to the Internal role I've set up for it.

Now that I've moved to ejb3 however, the user is being recognised, but it's telling me the user does not have any of the required roles...

I suppose my question is whether websphere or the spec has changed anything in that space that may be causing this, or whether it's more likely that something I've changed as part of the upgrade has caused it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an ibm-application-bnd.xmi file that maps users and groups to role's, this file must be in my_app.ear/META-INF.  Nothing appears to have changed with respect to that with the ejb3 feature pack, I had incorrectly removed it.